# how to change nba player projected point to 0 in a dataframe?

Tags: python

How to change micheal jordan and larry bird project 'FPPG' to 0?
please help!

```
raw_data=pd.read_csv(r'C:\DFS\nFire12_31_2022.csv')
```

---

```
Players         FPPG
 Luka Doncic     60
 Micheal Jordon  72
 Larry Bird      75
```

players_to_remove = `['Micheal Jordon','Larry Bird']`

```
 Players         FPPG
 Luka Doncic     60
 Micheal Jordon  0
 Larry Bird      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach (filtering records by specific column values ensured by [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) function):

```
df.loc[df.Players.isin(['Micheal Jordon', 'Larry Bird']), 'FPPG'] = 0
```

---

```
          Players  FPPG
0     Luka Doncic    60
1  Micheal Jordon     0
2      Larry Bird     0
```